# How to avoid copying headers from input to output in a Spring Integration @ServiceActivator method

Tags: java, spring-integration

I am using simple code to handle messages from Google PubSub subscription and return the results into a topic.
But for some reason, all headers added to the input message appear also on the output message headers.

Is there a way to get rid of this behavior?

The handling code looks like this:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "myInput", outputChannel = "myOutput")
public Message<String> onMessage(String payload, @Headers Map<String,Object> headers) throws SocketTimeoutException {
...
  return new GenericMessage<>(responseJson, Collections.singletonMap("type", "something"));
}
```

I did not find any mention in the Spring Integration docs about this "cloning" from input to output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't; if you use `@Transformer` instead (and return a `Message<?>`) the inbound headers are not propagated.

Comment: Thanks @Gary Russell - can you indicate how that can be done? I don't see how to access headers from a transformer methods, and how to build the resulting message (and set type header on it).

Comment: got it thanks; just used `@Transformer` annotation instead of `@ServiceActivator` and it works as expected